# How to remove markers and groups from leaflet.markercluster that do not fit within a cluster?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have a Leaflet.js map with a list of all the automobile fatalities in Spokane, WA for the past 10 years: https://codepen.io/dangayle/pen/NMJRLQ

```
const map = L.map('mapid').setView([47.657754, -117.426300], 11);
const accessToken = "pk.eyJ1IjoiZGFuZ2F5bGUiLCJhIjoiY2ltd2c4NWR3MDM4MnZxbHVjeHhlM2I4YiJ9.WN9nil2nsgakEItZXuQd_A"

function button(label, container) {
    var btn = L.DomUtil.create('button', '', container);
    btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    btn.innerHTML = label;
    return btn;
}

const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 16,
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
    accessToken: accessToken
}).addTo(map);

const markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
  maxClusterRadius: 100
});

axios.get('https://spokesmanreview.s3.amazonaws.com/crash-data/three-plus-vehicles.geojson')
  .then(function (response) {
    const features = response.data.features
    for ( let i=0; i < features.length; i++ ){
      const row = features[i];
      const title = row['properties']["REPORT NUMBER"];
      const marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(row['geometry']['coordinates'][1], row['geometry']['coordinates'][0]), { title: title });
      markers.addLayer(marker)
    }
    map.addLayer(markers);

  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

We are interested in isolating hot spots on the map, clusters of incidents at specific intersections. I need to filter out the extraneous markers to make it easier to spot those hot spots.

How do I remove markers that do not fit within a cluster at maxZoom and other small (n<5) clusters from leaflet.markercluster?

Answer (score 3):

The quick & dirty approach would be to create invisible markers instead of removing them. e.g.:

```
// In your CSS
.invisible-marker {
    display: none;
}

// In your JS
marker = L.marker([lat,lng], {icon:
  L.divIcon({
    className: 'invisible-marker'
  })
}).addTo(myClusterGroup);
```

That would make your individual markers invisible. For small groups, leverage Leaflet.Markercluster's `iconCreateFunction` option, e.g.:

```
var myClusterGroup = L.markerClusterGroup({
        iconCreateFunction: function (cluster) {
            var markerCount = cluster.getAllChildMarkers().length;

            if (markerCount <= 5) {
                return L.divIcon({ className: 'invisible-marker' });
            } else {
                 // Return your default cluster icon here
            }
        }
});
```

Remember to check Leaflet documentation about `L.DivIcon`, and the Leaflet.MarkerCluster examples for `iconCreateFunction`.

Comment: That's an interesting solution. I'll definitely try that.